# comparing float 0 to 0 - php

Tags: php

In the following code, I expect the `if` condition to be true, but actually the `else` condition is true. Can anyone explain the reason behind it?

```
$a = (float) 0;
$b = 0;
if ($b === $a) {
    echo "$a and $b are equal";
}
else{
    echo "$a and $b are not equal";  // true
}
```

Comment: use `==` - it matches values not based on type, `===` matches value and type

Comment: Why are you `echo`ing the same string?

Comment: You're echoing the same string in both conditions. How do you know which part is being triggered if they're both the same?

Comment: @Syscall sorry, edited the question

Comment: *in the following code, I expect "if" condition to be true* - why? If you know what triple equals does in PHP, then you shouldn't ever expect it to return true for different data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` part is `true` because `int(0)` and `float(0)` is not equal when you try with `===`, the `if` part will be true if you try with `==`. See their datatype with `var_dump($a)` or `var_dump($b)`

`===` not only compares **value** are equal but also ensures that entries are of same **type**

```
<?php
$a = (float) 0;
$b = 0;
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
if($b === $a){
    echo "$a and $b are equal";
}else{
    echo "$a and $b are not equal";  // true
}
?>
```

Comment: did you know that the var_dump function is variadic?

Comment: thanks, now i have understood,

Comment: @nik best of luck. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

=== checks if the value (0 & 0) and type (int & float) are equal.
In this case they are not.

If you want to only check the value and not the type then use ==

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)